# Change iframe src onchange of dropdown value

Tags: html, iframe, drop-down-menu, src

I am able to change the source of an iframe very easily with a "button" click.  But no matter what I try, I can't make the same happen with the use of a dropdown.

This works:

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="google.com" target="iframe">google</a>

<iframe name="iframe" src="yahoo.ca"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

But this does not:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="change">
<select name="options" target="iframe">
<option><a href="google.com" target="iframe">google</a></option>
</select>
</form>

<iframe name="iframe" src="yahoo.ca"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  I found other posts similar, but all involved the use of arrays - which I don't believe I should need?

Comment: I should mention:  above is a very dumbed-down version of my page - I am just trying to get the logic down.

Answer (score 16):

You need to use JavaScript

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="change">
<SELECT NAME="options" ONCHANGE="document.getElementById('youriframe').src = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option>choise</option>
<option value="http://microsoft.com">Microsoft</option>
</SELECT>

<iframe name="iframe" id="youriframe" src="yahoo.ca"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are amazing! thanks a million!  and so quick too!

Comment: And this is the problem I have seen with many users, who does not accept the answer and just disappears after their problem is resolved. Please learn to appreciate others help by accepting the answers

Answer (score 2):

Actually i needed to reload multiple iframes on dropdown change (3 different iframes on dropdwon choice), so i have ended up with this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function setIframeSource() {
            // behavior of myIframe
            var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
            var theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
            var theUrl;
            theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            theIframe.src = theUrl;

            // behavior of myIframe2
            var theSelect2 = document.getElementById('location');
            var theIframe2 = document.getElementById('myIframe2');
            var theUrl2;
            theUrl2 = theSelect2.options[theSelect2.selectedIndex].value;
            theIframe2.src = theUrl2;

            // behavior of myIframe3
            var theSelect3 = document.getElementById('location');
            var theIframe3 = document.getElementById('myIframe3');
            var theUrl3;
            theUrl3 = theSelect3.options[theSelect3.selectedIndex].value;
            theIframe3.src = theUrl3;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post">
       <label> Selecione a rede</label>
        <select id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()"> 
          <option value="http://example.com/">Example.com</option> 
          <option value="https://www.dell.com/">DELL</option> 
          <option value="https://www.americanas.com.br/">AMERICANAS</option> 
          <option value="https://www.bbc.com/">BBC</option> 
       </select>
    </form>
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://example.com/" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="800" height="250"></iframe>
        <br><br><hr/>
    <iframe id="myIframe2" src="http://example.com/" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="800" height="250"></iframe>
        <br><br><hr/>
    <iframe id="myIframe3" src="http://example.com/" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="800" height="250"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used this reference and another one, and came with this working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setIframeSource() {
            var theSelect = document.getElementById('location');
            var theIframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
            var theUrl;

            theUrl = theSelect.options[theSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            theIframe.src = theUrl;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post">
   <label> Selecione a rede</label>

    <select id="location" onchange="setIframeSource()"> 
      <option value="https://www.dell.com/">CNN</option> 
      <option value="https://www.americanas.com.br/">AMERICANAS</option> 
      <option value="https://www.bbc.com/">BBC</option> 
   </select>
</form>

<iframe id="myIframe" src="https://www.bbc.com/" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="800" height="400"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```