# Change code with drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I've trying to figure out how to change a html code with a drop-down menu.

This is what I currently have

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Languages</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=uk" target="test">English</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=de" target="test">German</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=fr" target="test">French</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=es" target="test">Spanish</a>
        <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=it" target="test">Italian</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

This changes the iFrame which is below the drop-down.

```
 <iframe name="test" src="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=uk" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

Under the iFrame I have a pre code showing how to embed the above iFrame.

```
<pre><code>&lt;iframe&gt;src="Path of the zip file" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
          </code></pre>
```

Javascript I'm using

```
    /* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to implement the link for where the iFrame folder is hosted to change when the user would click the drop-down menu and select a language.

For example, the user would click the drop-down menu and select German. The pre code will display the iframe with the link to the german folder. (hope that makes sense)

If someone could assist me with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Seb

Comment: If someone could help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

can you take a look at this approach and check if it helps:

[Change iframe src onchange of dropdown value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505039/change-iframe-src-onchange-of-dropdown-value)

Comment: sorry this isn't what I was looking for but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

**Dropdown**

```
     <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Languages</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=uk" target="test">English</a>
          <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=de" target="test">German</a>
          <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=fr" target="test">French</a>
          <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=es" target="test">Spanish</a>
          <a href="(URL LINK)/clients/1080/Canon.html?lc=it" target="test">Italian</a>

        </div>
      </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    myFunction() {
        $("#myDropdown > a").on('click', function(){
            var url= $(this).attr('href'); //Get URL from a href
            var $iframe = $('#iframeId'); // Get Iframe id
            $iframe.attr('src',url);    // Insert new URL

            var v= $('#code').text(); //get Iframe inside code tags
            var code = jQuery('<div />').html(v).text(); //Convert to HTML object
            var n = $(code).attr("src",val); //change the src
            var fin = $(n).prop("outerHTML"); //get the HTML
            var finHTML = jQuery('<div />').text(fin).html(); //Convert HTML into HTML entities
            $('#code').text(finHTML); // Change code HTML
        });
    }
```

**IFrame**

```
<iframe src="#" id="iframeId"></iframe>
```

**Code IFrame**

```
<pre><code id="code">&lt;iframe src="Path of the <strong>zip file downloaded from email</strong>" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
      </code></pre>
```

[Bootply Link](http://www.bootply.com/KAcscD3FTm)

The myFunction() gets the URL of the clicked href using attr and the gets the iframe from the HTML entities from code and converts it into HTML object, then writes back the HTML entities back to code.

Comment: Just tried the above and it doesn't respond or display anything when the user would change the language.

Comment: I already have this implementation but I use target with name.

What I'm trying to do is display the iframe source path in the pre code.

Comment: @Seb understood your problem. Let me try something.

Comment: @Seb I have updated the code. Please try it now. It is done by converting html entities to html and vice versa.

Comment: I've tried implementing the code but it seems to interfere with my javascript which allows the drop-down to work.

Is there a way to overwrite that?

Comment: I've added my javascript I use for the drop-down function but I don't understand how to implement yours to make it work. I've checked your Bootply and it works perfect however i dont know how to implement it to my coding.

Comment: Just understand the code after the newline inside `myFunction()`. That is the code that is doing the manipulation of iframe inside <code> tags.

Comment: I understand but that code disables the drop-down from working :(